# Updated variable is not rendered

Tags: reactjs, state, use-state, react-functional-component, rerender

I am using react.

```
import React from 'react';

function Scheduler(props) {
    var remainingHours = 5;
    const TimelineHeaderItem = () => {
        remainingHours = 8;
        console.log(remainingHours) // prints 8
        return <></>;
    }
    const name = () => {
        console.log('fetching remaining hours=>', remainingHours); // prints 5
    }

    return (
       <>
        <TimelineHeaderItem /> 
        {name()} 
       </>
    );
}
export default Scheduler;
```

As you can see, I have changed the value of `remainingHours` to 8 in `TimelineHeaderItem`.
But when I access that value in `name` function, then it prints `5` which is the previous one.
Why is this so ? and how can I access updated value.

Comment: You need to use hook so React can be aware of its state change.

Comment: Yes, I can use `useState` but, My question is, why am I getting old value if I have already changed before ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React, what is displayed on the screen should flow from the state of the component. Changing the state of the component tells React to re-render the component. Simply reassigning a variable by itself, like you're doing, has no side-effects.

Also, the `TimelineHeaderItem` doesn't make sense - it's not returning anything. If you want it to change the `remainingHours`, use a plain function for that, rather than trying to render it as a component.

On a similar note, if you want `name` to show the remaining hours on the screen, make it a component instead of calling it inside the JSX. (or remove it entirely and just interpolate the `remainingHours` into the JSX.) Something along the lines of:

```js
const App = () => {
    const [remainingHours, setRemainingHours] = React.useState(5);
    const changeHours = () => setRemainingHours(8);
    return <div>
        <button onClick={changeHours}>click</button>
        <div>{remainingHours}</div>
    </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Normal variables do not create rerenders.**

**State variables are one of the variables responsible for telling react to rerender**

> **At the time, when `TimelineHeaderItem` updated the variable, the state has already rendered and the `name` function has already called, so you cant see the variable value change**.

Here is the result of `console.log()`

[image]

You have to use the variables as a `state` variables as they causes rerenders.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function Scheduler(props) {
    const [remainingHours, setHours] = useState(5); //<-- this is state
    const TimelineHeaderItem = () => {
        setHours(8);
        console.log(remainingHours) // prints 8
    }
    useEffect(() => { 
        TimelineHeaderItem(); //<-- this is useEffect, it runs on first render if provided with no dependecies
    },[]);
    
    const name = () => {
        console.log('fetching remaining hours=>', remainingHours); // prints 5
    }

    return (
       <>
        {/*<TimelineHeaderItem />  <--- No need of this now */}
        {name()} 
       </>
    );
}
```

u can read more about hooks and their functions here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
export default Scheduler;

Comment: My question is only why I am getting old value if I have already changed before ?

Comment: Because `name` still has the value `5` after the initial render.